# Can I use Session object in WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I would like to use Session object in a WCF service. I have a application in which I want to keep my in memory database in a Session or Session like object in WCF. I would like to use per session in memory database (for each user). I would like to expose it using WCF. Is there way to use Session in WCF or any other way to store session like object at WCF.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer following link, it will help you...
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/322436/RestSessionState